# Make a viewPage which below a button can scroll

Tags: android

I had a button over a viewPage.
I want to make button can respond single tap,and viewPage can respond drag.
I had try below,but it didn't worked.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        return true;
    }
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        return false;
    }
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        return true;
    }
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
        return false;
    }
}
```